# My program needs to use a third-party software located in the Debug folder, but the program says no config file was found. C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a simple tweaker for Discord and I want to use for that EasyRP.

Ok so it's a button that executes it. Nothing very difficult here.
EasyRP uses a config.ini file. Not obvious, but not difficult too.
When launching the program from MY program, EasyRP says no config file is found!
However, when I run it in its folder, everything runs fine.
Here's my (simple) code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    const string message = "Would you like to edit the config file before starting your discord presence? If you don't do so, your old presence will be applied!";
    const string caption = "Hynx DiscTweaks Warning";
    var result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

    if (result == DialogResult.No) {
        Process.Start(@"tweaks\easyrp\config.ini");
        Process.Start(@"tweaks\easyrp\easyrp.exe");
    }

    if (result == DialogResult.Yes) {
        Process.Start(@"tweaks/easyrp/config.ini");
    }
}
```

Comment: Poorly written programs require you to set the ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory property.

Comment: sorry but i'm new to C# and i don't understand what you're talking about? how do I ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The debug folder is used when you are debugging locally on your machine and is not created when the application is pushed to production. You should use relative linking to execute code in another file. You may have to traverse the file system to reach the correct file. If you are able to look at where your application is deployed and where EasyRP is deployed you can easily find out how to execute the files.

Comment: well yeah but what if the guy who is using my program decides to change the folder directory? will it ruin everything?

Comment: one option would be to package all your dependencies and your service together